# iOS app IPA compression vs. zip compression

Tags: ios

I have an application that I'm hoping to submit to the AppStore. In the US, AT&T imposes a 20MB download limit for a single app for users on 3G data, so I want to make sure my app is under 20MB in size. So the question is: When I compress the final and built app (the one that I submit to Apple), the size comes out to 20.3 MB. But when I do build and archive to create an IPA, the size of the IPA comes out to 19.2 MB. Which one should I go by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the one you submit that counts: the IPA file.